# heroku timeout error H12 when calling API

Tags: python, flask, heroku, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Im receiving a heroku timeout error with code H12 when Im calling an api via my flask app. The api usualy responds within 2min. Im calling the api via a different thread so that the main flask app thread keeps running.

```
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(shub_api, website, merchant.id)
        result = future.result()
```

There is some documentation on Heroku on running background tasks, however the python examples were for using Redis that i know nothing about. Are there some other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working because of the way Heroku is architected.

When your web application is deployed to Heroku, it runs on [dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos). Dynos are "ephemeral webservers" that only live for a small amount of time. This means that when a user makes a request to your app, the user's request will be handled by a dyno that may only live for a short period of time.

Heroku dynos are constantly starting, stopping, and being moved around to other physical hosts. This means that web dynos should not be used to run tasks that take a long time to complete (there are different [worker dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) for that).

Furthermore, every web request that is served by a Heroku dyno has a 30-second timeout. What this means is that if someone makes an HTTP request to your app on Heroku, your app must start responding to the client within 30 seconds, otherwise, [Heroku's routing layer will issue an H12 TIMEOUT](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout) error to you because it thinks your app has frozen or gotten stuck in a loop somewhere.

To sum it up: Heroku's architecture is such that it is designed from the ground up to follow web best practices, which means having your HTTP requests finish quickly (< 30 seconds) and not relying on your web servers being permanent fixtures where you can just run code on them all the time.

What you should do to resolve this issue instead is to use a background worker process (essentially it's just a second type of dyno you can run some code on that will process long-running tasks) and have your web application send a notification to your worker process to start running your task code.

This is typically done via a message queue like Redis, AWS SQS, etc. [This Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) explains the concept in more detail.